# Cocos2d: CCLabelTTF call function?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

I have a menu that is comprised of `CCLabelTTF`s and now I want call a function when each is click/taped on. I'm just wondering if you can do this with `CCLabelTTF` or is I have to `CCMenuItemLabel`. Also if I have to use `CCMenu`, could someone explain how to arrange the items that are in the menu, as I have had no luck in that regard. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code it works for the CCMenuItemLabel

```
CCLabelTTF *lbl_Home = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"HOME" fontName:@"verdana" fontSize:25];
CCLabelTTF *lbl_Home1 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"HOME" fontName:@"verdana" fontSize:25];
CCLabelTTF *lbl_Home2 = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"HOME" fontName:@"verdana" fontSize:25];
CCMenuItemLabel *lbl1 = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:lbl_Home target:self selector:@selector(homeClicked1)];
CCMenuItemLabel *lbl2 = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:lbl_Home1 target:self selector:@selector(homeClicked2)];
CCMenuItemLabel *lbl3 = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:lbl_Home2 target:self selector:@selector(homeClicked3)];
// Your Menu creation starts here 
CCMenu *mnu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:lbl1,lbl2,lbl3,nil];
[mnu setPosition:ccp(winSize.width/2+100,winSize.height/2+100)];
[mnu alignItemsVertically]; // as u need either vertical or horizontal alignment
[self addChild:mnu];
```

Comment: ok I get that; but the problem is my Items need to be in a table-esk format. So I need to be able to align my items in rows/columns.

Comment: CCLabelTTF class is not available in android?

Comment: I dont know about android :( . @Dhrupal

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that I just pulled from my current project, using blocks:

```
CCMenuItemLabel *myLabel = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:[CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"LabelString" fontName:@"Times New Roman" fontSize:20]
                                                           block:^(id sender) {
                                                               // execute code here...
                                                           }];
```

For ordering of elements, when you add them to your menu, like this:

```
CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:button1,  button2, button3, button4, nil];
```

The order you put them in there is the order they show on screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can align items in a CCMenu either vertically or horizontally. CCMenu does not support a grid-like table layout unless you modify the CCMenu class (or subclass it).

Not sure if this code still works (it's 2 years old by now) but I once developed a [CCMenuGrid](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/3194) for exactly that reason.